# hide / show action bar in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-runonuithread

I have `MainActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity`. In that 3 fragments which can be changed by sliding gesture. I want to remove action bar in middle one. And Add action bar again when user slide in 1st or 3rd fragment.

I have below code:

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    if(menuVisible && getActivity()!=null){
        getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}

@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible) {
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    if(menuVisible){
        getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

But, it's giving me below warning:

> Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I tried to put that in:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         // hide / show action bar...
    }
});
```

App is lagging. How can I make it smooth?

Comment: Are you using ActionBar or can you go for a toolbar?

Comment: Can you consider use `getSupportActionBar().show()`/`getSupportActionBar().hide()`?

Comment: @betorcs: There is no such a method in my case. I also tried with `getActivity().getActionBar().show();`. But, in that case also app is crashing: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.show()' on a null object reference`

Comment: You need cast `getActivity()` to `AppCompatActivity`, so `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: @betorcs: Crashing: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.show()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Maybe you calling it, before fragment be attach to activity.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code snippet in the `onResume` callback of the middle `Fragment`

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
if (activity != null) {
    activity.getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

and in the `onResume` callback of the other two `Fragment`s add

```
AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
if (activity != null) {
    activity.getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```